# How to append to pandas csv file with manual input?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

my_dict = { 'Customer'    : [],
            'Product'     : []
            }

x = input("Customer:")
y = input("Product:")

my_dict['Customer'].append(x)
my_dict['Product'].append(y)



df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)


df.to_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8', index= True)
```

**Output**

```
,Customer,Product
0,Customer 1,Product 1
```

**Question**

How can I append new row If I run the script again and input new values?

**Example**

If I run the script again and my input would be `Customer 2` & `Product 2` and add new `index` too. I want the output to look like this in csv file:

```
,Customer,Product
0,Customer 1,Product 1
1, Customer 2, Product 2
```

But at the moment, it is just overwriting it.

Comment: Read the csv content into a pandas dataframe and then just append to that dataframe the new value and write to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to append the data to the existing data so try to read in the file and append the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

try: #tries to read in existing data.csv file
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8', index_col = 0)
except FileNotFoundError: #if no file exists yet, create an empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()


my_dict = { 'Customer'    : [],
            'Product'     : []
            }

x = input("Customer:")
y = input("Product:")

my_dict['Customer'].append(x)
my_dict['Product'].append(y)



df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(my_dict))


df.to_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8', index= True)
```

Comment: This is what I want, but forgot to mention about the index. Is it possible to +1 on each new data?

Comment: Bare excepts are a bad idea. Also my_dict does not exist when the except is triggered, so another exception will be caught instead of the FileNotFoundError.

Comment: Oh you're right. I changed it to `df = pd.DataFrame()` and added the appropriate error to the except.

Comment: @read_Python: An easy solution for the index would be to call `df = df.reset_index()` after appending. Maybe someone else has a prettier solution though.